# 360°-Videos using Device Orientation in HTML5-App

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, youtube, krpano

I'm planning to develop a HTML5-App which should be capable of playing 360°-Videos using the Device Orientation of the smartphone. By moving the smartphone the player should pan and tilt the video.
A first idea was to simply embed a YouTube-360-Video. But the YouTube-Browser-Player doesn't seem to make use of the device orientation, in contrast to the YouTube-App.
My second idea is to use krpano and to hand over the orientation to the krpano-player.
Is this possible or do you have another idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the 360° video in question is equirectangular, which most of those videos are, you can use a little Three.js and the deviceorientation events to make your own player, [like in this example](https://github.com/AVGP/360-video-device-orientation-demo)